# Passing arguments to ruby interpreter when stdin is used as ruby source

Tags: ruby, ssh, wget

I built a rails deploy dashboard that kicks off a ruby script on a remote machine to update a deployed application.

The command to run the script looks like this:

```
ssh test-host-02 
  "wget -q -O - http://server/deploy.rb | sudo ruby" 
  > /tmp/update-test-host-02.log 2>&1
```

Now I need to pass arguments into the deploy.rb script. Such as which build to deploy.

What is the best way to pass arguments to deploy.rb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby follows  the standard convention of allowing you to specify stdin input with `-`, which allows you to pass arguments after.

```
$ ruby -- - HELLO
puts ARGV.first # outputs HELLO
```

The double-dash isn't necessary in most cases.

Another option is to use turn the output of wget into a file descriptor using bash's `<()` operator:

```
$ ruby <(wget -O - http://example.com/deploy.rb) option1 option2 ...
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the tip. I'm surprised that the ruby manpage doesn't cover this.

Answer (score 2):

I'd modify the `wget` line:

```
"wget -q -O http://server/deploy.rb && sudo ruby deploy.rb -p 1 --another parm"
```

I haven't tested it, but the idea is to chain Ruby's invocation rather than pipe into it.

Comment: `sudo ruby <(wget -q -O - http://server/deploy.rb) -p 1 --another param` would also work if he didn't want to save deploy.rb to disk for some reason.  That said, piping works for me (maybe there are some downsides I'm not aware of).

Comment: +1 @cam, good idea. I'd recommend adding that to your answer. :-)